# A step in a proof that has to do with cyclic groups/equality/divisibility

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $G$ is a group such that $\operatorname{ord(G)} = pq$ where $p, q$ are prime. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G.$ Then $\operatorname{ord(H)} \mid pq$ and so it's possible that $\operatorname{ord(H)} = p.$ If $h \neq e \in H$, then $\operatorname{ord(h)} \mid p$ and so $\operatorname{ord(h)} = p \ldots$

How do we know $p \mid \operatorname{ord(h)}$ or $\operatorname{ord(h)} \not < p$ so that $\operatorname{ord(h)} = p$?

Comment: The order of any element in a finite group divides the group's order. Yet if this order is a *prime* then there aren't many divisors...

Comment: If all you know is that $1\ne h\in H$ where $H$ is a proper subgroup of a group of order $pq$, where $p,q$ are prime, then you have no way of knowing whether $h$ has order $p$ or order $q$.

Comment: @almagest or order $pq$.

Comment: @Joanpemo, you nailed it. I somehow ignored the primality of $p, q$.